# hadoop not working after reboot without stopping dfs

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I installed hadoop 2.6 and everything seemed to work. I then rebooted all the machines without stopping the dfs first and I'm getting the errors below. Any way to fix it?

```
$ ./sbin/start-dfs.sh 

./sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 55: $hadoop/bin/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
Starting namenodes on []
./sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 60: $hadoop/bin/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: No such file or directory
./sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 73: $hadoop/bin/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: No such file or directory
./sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 108: $hadoop/bin/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory


~/hadoop$ ./bin/hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

HADOOP_HDFS_HOME not found!
~/hadoop$ ./bin/hdfs namenode -format
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the environmental variable in your .bashrc and hadoop-env.sh

```
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```